# Azure Devops not supporting build-args with Docker@2

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile

I need to pass the build id parameter from Azure Devops to a dockerfile from a yaml pipeline. Unfortunately Azure Devops doesn't support the docker `build-args` parameter as below.

> Be aware that if you use value buildAndPush for the command parameter, then the arguments property will be ignored.
> [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#arguments)

Is there any other way to pass arguments from Azure Devops through to a dockerfile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any other way to pass arguments from Azure Devops through to a dockerfile?

Yes. The **BuildAndPush** Command doesn't support adding argument.

But the **Build** command support it.

You could split buildandpush into Docker build task and docker push task.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Docker Build 
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: $(imageRepository)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
    tags: 5.12.4
    arguments: '--build-arg test_val="$(build.buildid)" '
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Docker Push
  inputs:
    command: push
    repository: $(imageRepository)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    tags: 5.12.4
```

Docker Build Step Result:

[image]

Comment: There has to be an additional step. Exact same code and it doesn't work.

Comment: Why does microsoft ignore `arguments` silently instead of throwing an exception which explains you can not use `buildAndPush` with `arguments` when you try to do it. would have saved me some hours of troubleshooting...

Answer (score 1):

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: 'MY Container Registry'
    repository: 'my-repo/my-image'
    Dockerfile: dockerfile.api
    tags: |
     latest
     $(Build.BuildId)
    arguments: '--build-arg major=$(BuildMajor) --build-arg minor=$(BuildMinor) --build-arg build=$(Build.BuildId) --build-arg revision=$(BuildRevision)'

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push
  inputs:
    command: push
    containerRegistry: 'MY Container Registry'
    repository: 'my-repo/my-image'
    tags: |
     latest
     $(Build.BuildId)
```

If you are looking for multiple build args, thats how you can do it.