# Azure pipeline pass env variable to dockerfile

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am working with a c# project that relies on a private Nuget feed. My intent is to have a dockerfile to take care of the restore and build process, but this constantly fails because i am not able to authenticate correctly to the feed package. following some documentations everybody is advising to have a `nuget.config` as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="local" value="https://url/_packaging/feed-name/nuget/v3/index.json"  />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Once configured this, to configure docker file with env variables, so i did:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /src
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh
COPY . .
#RUN ls
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV FEED_ACCESSTOKEN $FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"same url as in nuget.config", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"
RUN echo $VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS
RUN dotnet restore "./project.csproj"
```

while my pipeline is this:

```
- task: Docker@2
    name: 'dockerBuildAndPush'
    displayName: 'docker - Build & Push'
    inputs:
      repository: $(imageRepository)
      Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
      containerRegistry: ${{ variables.serviceconnection }}
      buildContext: ${{ variables.buildContext }}
      tags: |
        $(Build.BuildNumber)
        latest
```

I did created a `PAT` with read and write permission and created a variable in the pipeline named `FEED_ACCESSTOKEN`

but when i run the build and echo the VSS, i see that the password value is empty.

Its been a rough and long day and i cannot see my mistake. If anyone can kindly help me to understand what i am doing wrong, i would be grateful

And please if you have any question, just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The [`buildAndPush` task doesn't not support the build arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64345743/8843952)
But you need build arguments to push your secret (PAT), the solution is to build the image first.

There is a [blog post of Damien Aicheh](https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/devops/2022/08/15/docker-secrets-azure-devops-en.html) that might help you, this involves building a docker image first.
His use case is: "Let’s imagine you have to build a dotnet project but you have some nugets package stored in the Azure DevOps artifacts section."

I think this matches your perfectly, his key takeaways are:

- Make sure to store the PAT in a secure variable inside a variables group of Azure DevOps.
- Define the secret id with the same environment variable FEED_ACCESSTOKEN like this: --secret id=FEED_ACCESSTOKEN.
- To be able to mount secrets in Docker with Docker BuildKit you must set the DOCKER_BUILDKIT env variable to 1 to activate it.